# How to using strings in blob triggers over isolated Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, imagesharp, dotnet-isolated

I'm using an Azure Function v4 (isolated process) and I have a Blob Trigger Function that receives "string", instead a "Stream" because currently are not supported.

How can I transform this string to a Stream.

The string should be an image that I want to manipulate with ImageSharp, but this library only works with Streams (not strings)

[image]

[image]

[image]

ImageSharp returns some errors related to decoding (I tried all possible options to decode)

Any suggestions?